# How to resolve this '! Undefined control sequence.' error?

Tags: latex3

When I tried to build .tex file, I got an error below.

```
(/home/haoki/texmf/tex/platex/plautopatch/plautopatch.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty)) (/home/haoki/texmf/tex/latex/jlreq/jlreq.cls
Document Class: jlreq 2021/11/05 jlreq
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (/home/haoki/texmf/tex/latex/jlreq/jlreq-helpers.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.399 \legacy_if:nF
                    { jlreq@option@titlepage } {
?
```

I can't understand what this error means clearly.
I assume the error occurred here.

```
\legacy_if:nF { jlreq@option@titlepage } {
  \str_if_eq:VnTF \jlreq@article@type { article } { \@titlepagefalse } { \@titlepagetrue }
}
```

Will you please explain what this error means?

Thank you.

Comment: `\legacy_if:nF` is defined in expl3 so predefined in current latex, so it means that your latex is too old for the class that you are using

Comment: if that is the only thing not defined then `\ExplSyntaxOn\def\legacy_if:nF#1{\exp_args:Nc \if_meaning:w {if#1}\iftrue \__prg_F_true:w \fi: \use:n\ExplSyntaxOff}` probably fixes that but other things may break depending on how old your system is.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I installed old Tex live version. I will replace it

Comment: I sugggest to write to the maintainer of plautopatch tp include a line that verifies it is running with the right LaTeX version, e.g. \NeedsTeXFormat... then people who pick up the new classes get a reasonable error message if they attempt to use it with an old LaTeX base format (as both need to go together)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Hmm that error is raised from jlreq.cls not my plautopatch.sty. I'll report to the jlreq author